Why EntityManager cant be found?
I am creating project which focuses on manufacturing a Car, so for that I created an Entity Class and Dao that uses EntityManager as shown below
package org.car_factory.car_factory_logic.dao;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.car_factory.car_factory_logic.entity.Car;

@Stateless
public class CarEJB {
    
      @Inject
      private Logger logger;
                
        @Inject
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public void createCar(Car carbody)
        {
            logger.info("Congratulations your car is created");
            entityManager.persist(carbody);
        }
        
        public void updateCar(Car carbody)
        {
            logger.info("Congratulations your car is updated");
            entityManager.merge(carbody);
        }
        
        
        public void removeCar(Car carbody)
        {
            logger.info("your carbody is removed");
            entityManager.merge(carbody);
        }

}

and Logger is also set
package org.car_factory.car_factory_logic.utils;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class EntityManagerProducer {

      
        @Produces
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Produces
    public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint)
    {
        return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
    }
    
        
}

persistence.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/CarFactoryDB</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

   <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

beans.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans bean-discovery-mode="all" version="2.0"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"/>

pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


  <parent>
  <groupId>org.car-factory</groupId>
    <artifactId>car-factory</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  
  <artifactId>car-factory-logic</artifactId>
  <packaging>ejb</packaging>

  <name>car-factory-logic</name>
  <description>A simple car-factory-logic.</description>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>


  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <version>1.18.34</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
            <!-- Jackson Databind -->
        
   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
    

    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId> 
            <scope>provided</scope>
             <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.190</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m05-2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m05-2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
             <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
             <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>6.4.10.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
             <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
             <version>1.8.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.7.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
  
  

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.12.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.13.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>

The database Is also configured in wildfly.
however after deploying this jar file in wildfly I get.
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"car-factory-logic.jar\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYWELD0037: Error injecting persistence unit into Jakarta Contexts and Dependency Injection managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named '' in deployment car-factory-logic.jar for injection point private javax.persistence.EntityManager org.car_factory.car_factory_logic.utils.EntityManagerProducer.entityManager"}}

I tried also to update the dependencies but that also didn't help what else could be the issue.

There are a lot of mismatched dependencies in your POM as well. The WildFly BOM you're using is very old as is the javaee-api dependency. You've also got a mix of RESTEasy and Jersey which could be a problem. What container are you trying to run in?


The persistence.xml file should be located in the META-INF folder.

The persistence unit name in the @PersistenceContext annotation must match the one specified in the persistence.xml file:


@PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")


I tried that too. It didn't work.

@DAN Is the persistence.xml file located in the META-INF folder?

I Fixed it, the issue was that the name of the folder was META_INF.
THANKS!
